# Waiting for all elements to fully with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I've been trying to figure out how Promises work with a rather simple example: one that fetches a number of images, loads it onto the page in order, counts the number of images loaded.

```
const addImg = url => {
    fetch(url)
        .then(validateResponse)
        .then(readResponseAsBlob)
        .then(showImage)
        .catch(Error);
}

function showImage(responseAsBlob) {
    const container = document.getElementById('img-container');
    const imgElem = document.createElement('img');
    container.appendChild(imgElem);
    const imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(responseAsBlob);
    imgElem.src = imgUrl;
    return imgUrl;
}

document.getElementById("add").onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Fetching...";
    Promise.all(urls.map(url => addImg(url)))
        .then(setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length + " images";
        }, 0));
}
```

The addImg function fetches an image from the url, processes it as a blob and `showImage` renders adds a new img. When I try to add images from an array of urls, I have noticed a few problems I want to fix:

1. The images don't necessarily show up in order
2. the img count is not accurate

My first thought: if I deconstruct the addImg function so that it execute each step as a separate promise( fetch all -> then validate all -> then ... so on), it might work the way I intend it to, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach to it.

Comment: Yes, that would be the right approach.

Comment: Why are you using `fetch`, `validateResponse`, and `readResponseAsBlob`, instead of simply appending an `<img>` to the DOM? (That way it would be in the right position from the get-go as well)

Comment: @Bengi I'm trying to fetch from https://picsum.photos/400/300/?random , which generates a different image every time I access it. I'm trying to save the image as a blob to create a url for the img's src

Comment: Ah, ok. Of course you could just fetch from `"https://picsum.photos/400/300/?image="+Math.floor(Math.random()*1085)` :-)

Answer (score -1):

It might make more sense to you if you rewrote your code using async/await. If you rewrote your AJAX call as

```
const addImg = url => fetch(url)
      .then(validateResponse)
        .then(readResponseAsBlob)
        .then(showImage)
        .catch(Error);
```

And then you could do something like:

```
async function loadImages(){
  for(image in imageList){
    await addImg(image.url);
  }
  console.log('Images loaded');
}
```

This way your code will wait for each image load to complete before the next. Note that this isn't very performant but if you want them loading specifically in order then this is one you could achieve that easily.